# Verify installed rpm packages signatures

Tags: security, rpm, signature, integrity

I'm interested in checking the integrity of all installed rpm packages on the system.

In case I have the rpm file itself, I'll run `rpm -Kv PACKAGE.rpm`, but what can I achieve the same goal if I the original rpm is missing?

Is the signature and digest data are stored in the rpm database?

I know i can verify the files inside the rpm by `rpm -Va PACKAGE_NAME`, but it will only check the files digests and not the signature.

Answer (score 1):

If the package already has been installed, then it is too late - thou, there is a small chance that the package is still in /var/cache/{dnf,yum}/.

The best way to check signatures is to create a repo file (even if the baseurl will point to file location) and set `gpgcheck 1` in that repo file.

If you will ever run something like: `dnf install foo.rpm` then you should have in `dnf.conf` the variable `localpkg_gpgcheck` set to True, because the default is False.

Additionally, if you run `rpm -qi bash`, there is a information about a signature:

```
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Fri Dec  6 13:24:09 2019, Key ID 50cb390b3c3359c4
```

All gpg keys are imported in rpmdb and looks like other packages there. So you can do:

```
$  # suffix of the gpg key from the command above
$ rpm -qa |grep 9c4
gpg-pubkey-3c3359c4-5c6ae44d

$ rpm -qi gpg-pubkey-3c3359c4-5c6ae44d
Name        : gpg-pubkey
Version     : 3c3359c4
Release     : 5c6ae44d
Architecture: (none)
Install Date: Ne 18. srpna 2019, 15:49:39 CEST
Group       : Public Keys
Size        : 0
License     : pubkey
Signature   : (none)
Source RPM  : (none)
Build Date  : Po 18. února 2019, 17:58:53 CET
Build Host  : localhost
Packager    : Fedora (31) <fedora-31-primary@fedoraproject.org>
Summary     : gpg(Fedora (31) <fedora-31-primary@fedoraproject.org>)
Description :
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: rpm-4.14.2.1 (NSS-3)
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=6hRW
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

And you may decide whether this is a good key.

But I am afraid that this still does not tell you anything whether the rpm payload signature actually match that signed one. :(

Comment: An interesting thing I noticed is that if I ran ```rpm -qivv bash```, the debug output indicates that the signature is validated:
```D:  read h#     846 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: OK```
It seems that the signature of the package is stored in the rpm db, and tested each time a package is queried:
```rpm -qv --queryformat "%{SIGPGP}\n" bash```
But still I can't be sure that the signature is validated and not the hash of  the file